# How to make request to DirectAdmin with REST API?

Tags: php, asp.net, angularjs, rest, api

Does anyone know how I can make a query for API from DirectAdmin?
https://www.directadmin.com/api.php

I'm using AngularJS + .NET and I communicate with services via REST API - POST, GET, UPDATE, DELETE etc. but in documentation from directadmin there is not any URL where I can make request. There are only Commands: `CMD_ACCOUNT_RESELLER` etc. 
I guess this is for PHP services. So how can I communicate with that API in "normal way"?

Answer (score -1):

there is no RESTful API. DirectAdmin's API is that you found.

Here you can find full API documentation and available commands:

https://www.directadmin.com/api.php

Here is library to connect directadmin in some standarized way:

https://files.directadmin.com/services/all/httpsocket/

Here you have sample script:

www.directadmin.com/sample_api.txt

If you have any other questions let me know :)

Enjoy! :)